# Rank function on finitely generated module over a domain.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Say $M$ is a finitely generated module over a domain $R$.

Define a function $\mathrm{rk}_M \colon \mathrm{Spec} ( R) \to \mathbb{N}$ by setting $\mathrm{rk}_M(P)$ equal to the dimension of $M_P / PM_P$ as a $R_P / PR_P$ vector space.

It is well know that if $\mathrm{rk}_M$ is not constant on $\mathrm{Spec} (R)$, then $M$ is not projective, since $R$ is a domain.

I am curious about the converse: if $M$ is not projective, can we guarantee that $\mathrm{rk}_M$  is not constant?

If the converse is not true, are there standard examples which show this?

Comment: Certainly true at least when $R$ is Noetherian (may be even more generally).

Comment: @Mohan thanks for the reply. Do you happen to know a reference for the converse off the top of your head?

Comment: Any book on Commutative algebra, for instance Matsumura or Eisenbud.